# My jquery plugin throws exception

Tags: jquery, exception, plugins

I am working on a project to let the font change its color when moving mouse over it.
here is the version of without jquery plugin:
here is the html code part:

```
<div><a href="#" style="color:#000000;text-decoration:none;font-size:20px;" id="myFontDaemon"><strong>my web link places here</strong></a></div>
```

here is the javascript part:

```
    var tColorTimer;
    var myColorCollection = ["#FF6682", "#26FF51", "#263FFF", "#FF16B1", "#FFB135", "#C2B5FF","#000000"];

    //bind event
    function changeFontColorWhenHover() {
        $("#myFont").bind("mouseover", function () {
            changeFontColor(0);
        });
    }

    //change font color
    function changeFontColor(m) {
        var colorValue = myColorCollection[m];
        $("#myFont").css("color", colorValue);
        if (m < 7) {
            tColorTimer = setTimeout('changeFontColor(' + (m + 1) + ')', 100);
        }
    }

    //init bind
    $(document).ready(function () {
        changeFontColorWhenHover();
    });
```

above codes work correctly.
but when I turned them into a sample jquery plugin, it throws me exception as expected ']', I searched the jquery plugin a lot but can't find what I missed. 
here is the jquery plugin part:

```
    (function ($) {
    $.fn.fontdaemon = function () {
    this.each(function () {
        $(this).bind("mouseover", function () { // onmouseover event is raised
            changeFontColor($(this), 0);
        });
    });
    };

    var tColorTimer;

    var myColorCollection = ["#FF6682", "#26FF51", "#263FFF", 
    "#FF16B1", "#FFB135", "#C2B5FF", "#000000"];
function changeFontColor(obj, m) {
    var colorValue = myColorCollection[m];
    alert(m + "--" + colorValue);
    $(obj).css("color", colorValue);

    if (m < 7) {
        tColorTimer = setTimeout('changeFontColor(' + obj + "," + (m + 1) + ')', 50);
    }
    alert(m + "--" + colorValue);
};
})(jQuery);
```

then I use below code to call it:

```
<script src="fontdaemon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myFontDaemon").fontdaemon();
    });
</script>
```

when I move my mouse over the text, then it will change its color , but it will only change to first of the color in the color array , then it will throw me an exception as "Expected ']'".

Anyone can help me out? thx.

PS: I have searched google a lot, but can't find the solution, any feedback will be appreciate, thanks very much again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're passing a string into `setTimeout` (which is discouraged). When you pass a string into `setTimeout`, when the timeout has elapsed, it will `eval` the string without any access to your local variables. Since `changeFontColor` is not accessible out of the anonymous function passed to `$`, the code in the string passed to `setTimeout` cannot access it either.

The solution is to pass an anonymous function to `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function() { changeFontColor(obj, m + 1); }, 50);
```

By the way, it's not necessary to use `each` if all you're doing is `bind`ing; `bind` already binds to each of the elements in the jQuery object. It is also unnecessary to be doing `$(obj)` in `changeFontColor` since `obj` is already a jQuery object.